# powershell exchange : if then statement syntax?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

In my script i'm trying to test for true and false.  Is this syntax incorrect?

```
$pdaout = ""
if ($pda.ActiveSyncEnabled.tostring() -like "True") {$pdaout = "TRUE"}
if ($pda.ActiveSyncEnabled.tostring() -like "False") {$pdaout = "-"}

write-host $pdaout
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it would be better to just check the boolean value directly instead of using ToString():

```
$pdaout = ""

if ($pda.ActiveSyncEnabled -eq $True) { $pdaout = "TRUE" }
else { $pdaout = "-" }

write-host $pdaout
```

Here is a blog post from the [Windows Powershell team re: Boolean Values and Operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It should be, except may be for the `tostring()` function (use `toString()` to make sure there is no issue with the case sensitivity)

Plus, you may want to use [**`elseif`**](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/winpsh/convert/ifthen.mspx) to avoid doing a second test if the first one was successful:

```
if ($pda.ActiveSyncEnabled.toString() -like "True") {$pdaout = "TRUE"}
elseif ($pda.ActiveSyncEnabled.toString() -like "False") {$pdaout = "-"}
```